# Redirection at beginning of command with command in variable fails

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want to put a command string in a variable. This is what I am doing

`ssh=">/dev/null ssh -i key domain"`

Then I want to call this command:

`$ssh ls >&2`

But this fails with:

`bash: 1>/dev/null: No such file or directory`

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: That is the expected behavior.  It looks like you want `ssh() { > /dev/null command ssh -i key domain "$@"; }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is expected since you're trying to execute the non-existant command '>/dev/null...' due to the quotation marks.

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794728/variables-as-commands-in-bash-scripts

Comment: Do you know if it is mentioned somewhere in a manual that if supplied just a variable, the shell will treat it as containing the name of a command?

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for eval...

```
eval "$ssh ls >&2"
```

or

```
eval "$ssh ls" >&2
```